# Open new window with css and pictures

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am doing a simple print option that when click I call a print function.  The function copies over the relevant (not all of it) html.

```
function print() {

var printWindow = window.open("", "Print", "status=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes", "false" );
var toInsert = $("div.book").html();
$(printWindow.document.body).html(toInsert);

}
```

The problem I have is that this new window doesn't seem to be able to reference my css stylesheet or my pictures that are within the folder.  Any ideas?  Just focusing on the css issue, would it be possible to insert a `<link ... />` into the head of the new window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function Print() {
    var printWindow = window.open("", "Print", "status=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes", "false" );
    $("link, style, script").each(function() {
       $(printWindow.document.head).append($(this).clone())
    });
    var toInsert = $("div.book").html();
    $(printWindow.document.body).append(toInsert);​
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zCdrn/1)

Comment: This works except for the fact that the original web page is now missing the content for `link`, `style` and `script` (or at least this is the behavior of firefox 10.0.6). I have tried this: `$(this).clone().appendTo($(printWindow.document.head));` but no cigar.

Comment: @zanegray, yes you are right, the cloned elements must be appended. I've changed it, it seems working well for now.(for all browsers).

Answer (score 3):

It's a totally new window. It has to have its own CSS etc.

When you write a document into it, you have to write in the `<link>` tags, `<script>` tags, and everything else like that.

Comment: This answer is more accessible and less hacky than the answer that was accepted. People need to get less happy with the JavaScript!

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically insert a link to an existing CSS stylesheet into the head of the new window this worked well for me:

```
var cssNode = document.createElement('link');
cssNode.type = 'text/css';
cssNode.rel = 'stylesheet';
cssNode.href = 'http://www.somedomain.com/styles/FireFox.css';
cssNode.media = 'screen';
cssNode.title = 'dynamicLoadedSheet';
printWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(cssNode);
```

[Source: Totally Pwn CSS with Javascript](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript) - Has some other interesting tricks around direct manipulation of a stylesheet